# Why are logging statement in python evaluated regardless of level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Why are logging statement in python evaluated regardless of level?

In this code for example, I expected the "I was executed" statement to be printed only when the script is called with "-d", but it is always printed! This means that logging statement can have an unexpected impact on code run at higher logging levels.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import time
import argparse
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='==> %(module)s, %(funcName)s %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)

def logme():
    #time.sleep(10)
    print('I was executed ☠')
    return 'loggging all the things...'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", "-d",
                         action='store_true',
                         help="Debug mode (very verbose)",
                        )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.debug:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print('hello')
logging.debug('{}'.format(logme()))
print('bye')
```

Is this a bug in the logging module?

Comment: You called `logme()` **before** passing it to a `str.format()` call, let alone before the result of the `str.format()` is being passed to `logging.debug()`. That's just the standard order of execution for expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It boils down to how the statement is evaluated. In

```
logging.debug('{}'.format(logme()))
```

The parameter is evaluated first, then `logger.debug` is called. So, we evaluate `'{}'.format(logme())`, then pass the result to `logging.debug`. It's effectively

```
x = '{}'.format(logme())
logging.debug(x)
```

Let's test this out:

```
def run_later(x):
    print("function call")

def effect():
    print("parameter evaluation")

run_later(effect())
>>> parameter evaluation
>>> function call
```

Comment: This is the crux of the issue, and also nice and short, +1. I've also added an answer to discuss format strings with the `logging` module (simply for completeness).

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a bug in the logging module?

No. Firstly, the outputs *are* different (copied your code into `test.py`):

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> python test.py
hello
I was executed.
bye
```

vs.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> python test.py -d
hello
I was executed.
==> test, <module> loggging all the things...
bye
```

Secondly, if you call `logme()` at any point in your program `"I was executed"` will print to your screen. That's because `logme()` contains the statement `print('I was executed ☠')`. This particular behavior has *nothing* to do with the `logging` module. It prints to screen because you're *calling the `logme` function* when you do:

```
logging.debug('{}'.format(logme()))
```

However, *logging* is not the same as *printing*, which is why we see different outputs. The `"I was executed"` will *always* print when called, but note that `"==> test, <module> loggging all the things..."` was only *logged* when the `-d` flag is specified. It just so happens that you set up your logging config to *print* when it's called (i.e. `logging.basicConfig(format='==> %(module)s, %(funcName)s %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR`). You can log to files, or do other things of that sort.

### Using format strings with the `logging` module:

Furthermore, if you want to use a format string with the logger, you actually do it with the "%" style formatting, but you *don't* actually want to supply a format string. Instead, supply your formats as args. You'd do this because then the *format substitution won't happen unless the logger is called at the appropriate level*. Substituting into a format string is a relatively expensive operation, especially if (for instance) one of your debug statements is in a loop. Example of what I mean (replace your `logging.debug` statement with the one below):

```
# logging.debug('{}'.format(logme()))    
logging.debug('Some %s format %s string', 'first', 'second')
```

Then we have:

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> python test.py
hello
bye
```

and:

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> python test.py -d
hello
==> test, <module> some first format second string
bye
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer tell you why `logme()` is always evaluated, but if you really want you can avoid it by ensuring that `logme` is only called if the result is converted to a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import time
import argparse
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='==> %(module)s, %(funcName)s %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)

class LazyStr:
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kw):
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kw = kw

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fn(*self.args, **self.kw))


def logme(n, foo):
    #time.sleep(10)
    print('I was executed, n=%d, foo=%s' % (n, foo))
    return 'loggging all the things...'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", "-d",
                         action='store_true',
                         help="Debug mode (very verbose)",
                        )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.debug:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print('hello')
logging.debug('%s', LazyStr(logme, 42, foo='bar'))
print('bye')
```

The `LazyStr` object will always be created, but the `logme()` function is called only if log level is `debug`. I added some arguments to `logme` as well to show how you can pass through arguments.

Output:

```
$ ./t.py
hello
bye
$ ./t.py --debug
hello
I was executed, n=42, foo=bar
==> t, <module> loggging all the things...
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the logging function that the decision to do something is made, which is why logging.debug has to at least be entered.  Your logme function is run and evaluated before then so that its result can be passed in, which is why you see "I was executed ?" printed.